# Installing Openstack errors

Tags: git, openstack, devstack

I have no experience in openstack and would appreciate anyone who can help and guide me with this issue. I'm installing openstack in virtual environment (Ubuntu 12.04) and this came out:

> - git clone git//git.openstack.org/openstack/requirements.git/opt/stack/reqiurements
>     Cloning into '/opt/stack/requirements'... fatal:unable to connect to
>     git.openstack.org: git.openstack.org[0: 192.237.223.224]:
>     errno=Connection refused git.openstack.org[1:
>     2001:4800:7813:516:3bc3:d7f6:ff04:aacb]: errno=Network is
>     unreachable

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had the same problem, the git protocol is blocked in my testing environment.

The solution is to modify the **sourcerc** file in the devstack installation folder to use **https** instead of **git**. You have to look for that line and change it. This file is also known as the **local.conf** file.

Default setting in sourcerc file:

```
GIT_BASE=${GIT_BASE:-git://git.openstack.org}
```

Modified setting that should bypass git restrictions:

```
GIT_BASE=${GIT_BASE:-https://git.openstack.org}
```

Simply add this modified line to the local/localrc section of your **local.conf** file in the DevStack directory and it should use the HTTPS protocol instead of the Git protocol! More info on the **local.conf** file here - http://devstack.org/configuration.html

Comment: In Havana the file is called stackrc.

Comment: nice ty so for the info, I actually had to change the configuration to below
`GIT_BASE=${GIT_BASE:-https://github.com}`
thanks so much to our corporate firewall blocking git request access to **git.openstack.org**, but luckily openstack put the source code on github, and github is not blocked

Answer (score 10):

Make change in stackrc :

```
-GIT_BASE=${GIT_BASE:-git://git.openstack.org}

+GIT_BASE=${GIT_BASE:-https://www.github.com}
```

This would solve problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't help you with your particular error, but in general, the easiest way to install openstack is http://devstack.org/

Here are a few notes to install it on virgin Ubuntu 12.04 x64 server:

https://gist.github.com/max-lobur/7786074

This manual is about OpenStack together with Ironic project, but it won't affect you anyway. And you can omit "Install ironic client" step.

Answer (score 1):

In the git clone command replace the protocol - git:// with http://, in the repository URL and try. May be the network, to which your machine is connected, is prohibiting the git protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to "http" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is my custom bash script to install openstack ocata. It covers the installation of openstack core projects which includes keystone, nova, glance, nova, neutron and horizon dashboard.

Please follow the instructions in the document and execute the script in your environment. We can add additional compute node with this script.

https://github.com/techbhashya/openstack-ocata

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes git:// urls won't work. 
In such scenario you can use https instead of git.
use the following command:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```