# Openstack devstack installation stalls with git call failure

Tags: git, openstack, devstack

So my Openstack Devstack installation stalls with the following error:

> ./stack.sh:686:install_infra
>   /home/mycloud/devstack/lib/infra:45:git_clone
>   /home/mycloud/devstack/functions-common:545:git_timed
>   /home/mycloud/devstack/functions-common:599:die
>   [ERROR] /home/mycloud/devstack/functions-common:599 git call failed: [git clone git://git.openstack.org/openstack/requirements.git /opt/stack/requirements]

The solution after a bit of googling is found here: [Installing Openstack errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390267/installing-openstack-errors)
 ... and it works.

My question is what would make the "git" call fail and the "https" one work if git is installed and connectivity to the repository (as well as the rest of the Internet) is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely a firewall issue. The `git://` protocol runs on port 9418, while https:// uses port 443. Ports 80 and 443 are normally open in firewalls, other ports may need to be configured.

For more information: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol

Answer (score 8):

In case the GIT port is blocked on the firewall, you may also alter the installation by modifying stackrc file in devstack. You may change the line:

```
GIT_BASE=${GIT_BASE:-git://git.openstack.org}
```

to:

```
GIT_BASE=${GIT_BASE:-https://git.openstack.org}
```

or you may also try with `http`:

```
GIT_BASE=${GIT_BASE:-http://git.openstack.org}
```